# Append content to div on click without page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc

In my app I have an objects map as associative array, which I'm getting from JSON. This is a map which contains questions and four answers to each question. Next I'm trying to append a question to question div and answers as radio buttons to div answers. Everything seems to be working perfectly without one thing. After appending content to my divs page is reloading. So my question is how to prevent page reloading in this case. I tried using ajax call, but I unfortunately failed. 
My code is given below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var questions = [];
        $.getJSON("/exam/json", function (result) {
            var map = {};
            var response = result;
            for (var i = 0, l = response.length; i < l; i++) {
                map[response[i].id] = response[i];
            }
            $('#nextButton').click(function(){
                prepareQuestion(map);
            });
        });
    });
    function prepareQuestion(questionList){
        var actualQuestionIndex = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(questionList).length) + 1);
        $('#question').append(questionList[actualQuestionIndex].question);
        if(questionList[actualQuestionIndex].ansc === null){
            $('#answers').append("<input type='radio' name='ansa' value='A'>"+questionList[actualQuestionIndex].ansa+"<br>");
            $('#answers').append("<input type='radio' name='ansb' value='B'>"+questionList[actualQuestionIndex].ansb+"<br>");
        }else{
            $('#answers').append("<input type='radio' name='ansa' value='A'>"+questionList[actualQuestionIndex].ansa+"<br>");
            $('#answers').append("<input type='radio' name='ansb' value='B'>"+questionList[actualQuestionIndex].ansb+"<br>");
            $('#answers').append("<input type='radio' name='ansc' value='C'>"+questionList[actualQuestionIndex].ansc+"<br>");
            $('#answers').append("<input type='radio' name='ansd' value='D'>"+questionList[actualQuestionIndex].ansd+"<br>");
        }
        delete map[actualQuestionIndex];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Looking through your Javascript I cannot see anything that would cause the page to reload, and editing the DOM elements would not directly cause a page to reload. Could you please provide the HTML which this Javascript relates to?

Comment: according to your code snippet, your page cannot reload. you might be doing something else wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the button click propagating. try this:

```
$('#nextButton').click(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation()
                prepareQuestion(map);
 });
```

for reference please [read this link about event propagation.](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your button in a form. 
Then when you click on it, the form posts the page back. 
Because the post is slow, it will load the JSON first, then the reload will complete.

If you have defined your function in an onclick attribute, you'll need to add "return false;".

`onclick="somefunction(); return false;"`

otherwise, `event.stopPropagation()` is right.